# fetch API keeps returning internal error 500

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

I'm a beginner in using fetch API, I'm trying to fetch json data within react application but it keeps returning 500 (Internal Server Error)
The react application is running under http://localhost:3000/

I'v already added proxy in package.json file:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:3000"
```

Below is a sample json file data/greeting.json:

```
{
  "time": "am",
  "greeting": "Good morning"
}
```

caller.js file has a method to call json:

```
function getGreetings() {
    fetch(`./data/greeting.json`, {
        headers : {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Accept": "application/json"
        }
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((messages) => {console.log("messages");});
 }
```

Comment: It looks you are trying to load a file with fetch. You should reach an endpoint where you read the file whose content you want to retrieve.

Comment: yes I'm trying to get the data in json file, but I didn't get what you mean by reading the file, do you think there is something missing with my code?

Comment: I changed the location of json file into public folder in react application and it works fine!

Answer (score 2):

Since the JSON file also resides inside your directory, instead of using fetch for getting the data, you can just directly input the file content as trivial `require`.

In your context, you can do something like this:

```
const greeting = require('./data/greeting.json');
```

I hope this small code fragment will help.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the dot in your url (and possibly, the slash). If that's not it, then I'm guessing that there's something wrong with your server code.